# Files naming convention for external methods

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

I am wondering what is the difference between **utils** vs **helpers** vs **resolvers** vs **services** as a directory name for external methods. For example I want to create a special object that function as a list but can only pushed and not popped:

```
const specialObjectArray = () => {
    const objects = [];

    const object = {
        push: (data) => routes.push(data),
    };

    return object;
};
```

Which one it fits the most? 
What is the difference between the 4 names I listed above? Best Practice for those?

Comment: See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305511/is-it-good-to-have-utils-class-in-your-software-project) "Utils" vs. "Helpers" in Java, and [this issue](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/808) on "utils" and "helpers".

Comment: Also [this impassioned plea](https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/stop-naming-your-python-modules-utils/) against the use of "utils" in python in favor of "services", "validators", and "factories".